# how to apply system exit when pressing 0

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

so i have this factorial program that accepts input by the user. everything is working fine but I'm trying to figure out how to end the program by inputting 0. Since it's on a boolean operation i can't input an if statement because i would get a compile error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment2A {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean correct = false;
        while(!false){
            try{
                System.out.println("Welcome to the factorial function");
                System.out.println("Please enter a number or press 0 to exit");
                int n = scan.nextInt();
                // if(n=0){
                // System.exit(0);
                //}
                int factorial= fact(n);
                System.out.println("The Factorial of the number entered is: " + factorial);
                correct = true;
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("That is not a number!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    static int fact(int n){
        int output;
        if(n==1){
            return 1;
        }
        output = fact(n-1)*n;
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(!false){` is the same as `while(true){`

Comment: Should be `if (n == 0)`, NOT `(n=0)`

Comment: FYI: you don't need the sledgehammer that is `System.exit` here - just call `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't any (easy) way to do this. The closest equivalent would be to implement a `KeyListener`, but that's only for Swing methods (windows and stuff, not CLI).

Instead, you should check for if a certain value has been entered. For example, 0! is just 1, so you could have your program say "Enter a number to factor, or enter 0 to exit". You could also do this with negative numbers, since it doesn't look like your program would handle them well. On a side note, maybe you should add a check for negative numbers, too.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm a beginner as well but try this...

System.out.println("Welcome to the factorial function");

System.out.println("Please enter a number or press 0 to exit");

int n = scan.nextInt();

if(n==0)break; //place the break here and give it a try, tried using the exit and didn't work for me